# Update XPages text value from within a repeat?

Tags: xpages

I feel like I'm just not understanding something about the XPages lifecycle here.  I have an xp:text control, with a value of viewScope.count.  Initially, that's null.  After the xp:text, I have a repeat that's performing a calculation and returning an array of objects for its value.  At the end of the repeat's value section, I'm trying to update the xp:text with a count of the things in the array:

viewScope.count = myArray.length;

The xp:text isn't being updated with that value, though.  Should this work?  Do I need to do a manual refresh of the xp:text when I modify viewScope.count?  TIA!

Comment: Show the code! You might have the challenge of timing

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the index of the repeat to give you a count.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I was trying to simplify my question, but I may have simplified too much.  The repeat's value is actually a second array, which isn't the array length that I want to display in the text control.  The first array is computed and used in a second, nested repeat.  Sorry if this is confusing, but the bottom line is that just using the index won't work in this case.  (I'm a little unclear why that does work, though....)  FYI, this code sits on another network, so I can't paste it.

Comment: I don't think I understand the question then sorry.

Comment: That's okay, but my previous comment boils down to "I can't use the repeat row index".  To summarize: Why doesn't setting the viewScope data bound to the xp:text change the xp:text's value, and is there another solution that would work?  Thanks, though!

Comment: What happens if you refresh the text. If the page is loading everything then it does the repeats there is nothing that tells the text to load the values. There are a couple ways to accomplish this for production but the easiest way I can see for testing is to create a button that will just refresh the text or panel within it will then reload the values. You can see that is the problem.

Comment: Yes, I think something like this is indeed happening.  Strangely enough, I did what you suggested, wrapping the text in a panel and adding a button which partial refreshes just that panel; when I click on it, though, the panel disappears from the page! In another section of the page, though, I'm doing a different partial refresh, and the label does update at that time. I guess the question is still, how do I get the text to update (and not disappear) without user interaction such as a button?

Comment: You can use the events like onClientLoad, beforePageLoad, beforeRenderResponse etc. You can use these on Custom Controls or the page themselves to refresh components

Answer (score 1):

Take a step back and rethink the approach. Inside the code you use for your repeat you update something outside.

Not looking at 'does it work' I would claim 'bad idea'. Such side effects make maintenance a nightmare (and are not very MVC).

The better approach (IMHO):

Create an object data source. AFAIK that can be a JSON object if you are not comfortable with Java. That object would have all the needed properties for your repeat and your counter display. It serves as your model.

Then bind the repeat and the text field to the model and you are good.

Makes sense?

Comment: Yes, I'm certainly open to the idea that there's a better design!  Thank you.  Your idea sounds like a good design principle.  Where in the xpage would you suggest creating the object data source that would be the model for both the xp:text and repeat?  I originally put it in the repeat because that's where it's mainly used.  (This object is built from some parameters specified via form elements elsewhere on the page; it's basically the result of a search.)

Comment: There is a type object data source at the page level - same like a document data source location